# New OVI SDK for Symbian

Tags: symbian, s60, ovi

Has anyone tried the new OVI SDK for Symbian development?

What are your experiences?
Do you believe that it can help Nokia get more programmers building applications for Symbian based devices, or do you consider Flash Lite, Java or Python to be best choices?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it the Ovi SDK is a web based framework similar to or built on [WRT](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Web_Runtime_%28WRT%29_Quick_Start). This certainly fills a niche. My worry is that it will be tied to Nokia handsets only, and won't work with the other Symbian devices.

WRT, Python, Qt+Symbian C++ seem like safer bets for cross device compatibility.